# Django NoReverseMatch

Tags: django, url, django-templates

I have the following setup:

```
/landing_pages
    views.py
urls.py
```

In `urls.py` I have the following which works when I try to access `/competition`:

```
from django.conf.urls.defaults import *
from django.conf import settings
from django.views.generic.simple import direct_to_template

from django.contrib import admin
admin.autodiscover()

urlpatterns = patterns('',
    url(r'^competition$', 'landing_pages.views.page', {'page_name': 'competition'}, name="competition_landing"),
)
```

My `views.py` has something like this:

```
def page(request, page_name):
    return HttpResponse('ok')
```

Then in a template I'm trying to do this:

```
{% load url from future %}
<a href="{% url 'landing_pages.views.page' page_name='competition'%}">
    Competition
</a>
```

Which I apparently can't do:

> Caught NoReverseMatch while rendering: Reverse for 'landing_pages.views.page' with arguments '()' and keyword arguments '{'page_name': u'competition'}' not found.

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Have you seen [this](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.3/ref/templates/builtins/#url)? Compare your code with examples provided.

Comment: Don't you see any dirrerences between your code and examples there?

Comment: @DrTyrsan - Besides the examples there covering the deprecated url syntax, no. Do you?

Comment: @DrTyrsan - I did test it, read the documentation and scratched my head for a good while before coming here. So thanks for assuming I didn't and calling me lazy. You must be a blast at parties.

Comment: And you haven't realised that you shouldn't use quotes around view name? Ok.

Comment: @DrTyrsa - Unquoted url names are depricates as of Django 1.3 as I've mentioned. It's even in the documentation you linked to me. They are silently throwing an error in 1.3, will do so loudly in 1.4 and will be removed in 1.5. It's in the 1.3 release notes. `{% load url from future %}` enables the quoted version.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You ask in your comment to DrTyrsa why you can't use args or kwargs. Just think about it for a moment. The `{% url %}` tag outputs - as the name implies - an actual URL which the user can click on. But you've provided no space in the URL pattern for the arguments. Where would they go? What would the URL look like? How would it work?

If you want to allow the user to specify arguments to your view, you have to provide a URL pattern with a space for those arguments to go.

Comment: OHHHHHHHHHHH! I understand the issue now, thank you. That was very insightful for me.

Comment: I don't get it.. Could someone please explain a little more? ^^

Comment: @NiklasR Please post a new question rather than commenting on a 15-month-old answer.

Comment: Yea, I'm sorry..  But I already fixed it. I was running Django 1.4.? and had to include `{% load url from future %}` before using the url-tag with quotes..

Answer (score 0):

```
{% url [project_name].landing_pages.views.page page_name='competition' %}
```

Or better

```
{% url competition_landing 'competition' %}
```

Comment: @Kit Sunde Even second variation? Try to cause Http404 somehow (`/404`) and see wheteher your urls are imported.

Comment: Yes both (or all 3 including my example) produced the same error. I can access the page normally by going to `/competition` so the view and URL must be imported. In fact if I comment out the line from my url.py it stops working so there's nothing overriding it and handling it elsehwere.

Comment: And just `{% url competition_landing %}`? I think, no need to pass `page_name` if you are already passing it in urls.

Comment: Ah! That works. I still don't understand why I can't use args or kwargs with the view though.

Comment: I assume that if you pass a parameter in url, this url can't take this parameter again. Seems something like `functools.partial` to me.