# redirect error with django

Tags: django, redirect

I have a problem with the redirect of Django 1.4.3

```
#-*- coding: utf-8 -*-
from django.http import HttpResponse, Http404
from django.shortcuts import redirect

def redirect_test(request):
    print("redirect_test() called.")

    return redirect('redirectionFunc')

def redirectionFunc(request):
    return HttpResponse("You have been redirected.")
```

My url is :

```
url(r'^redirectTest/$', 'redirect_test')
```

When I try to open

```
http://xxx/blogz/redirectTest
```

I got the following error :

```
NoReverseMatch at /blogz/redirectTest/

Reverse for 'redirectionFunc' with arguments '()' and keyword arguments '{}' not found.
```

Whereas the terminal I have :

```
redirect_test() called.
```

What's wrong ??

Comment: check out this similar question http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6871226/django-noreversematch

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The 'redirect' method, takes the python path to the url, or the name of the url.

In the first case, if your "redirect_func" view is in app/views.py, your code should be:

```
return redirect('app.views.redirect_func')
```

If you want to name your url, for example "redirect_test", in your url configuration you should give the name parameter to the url method:

```
url(r'^redirectTest/$', 'app.views.redirect_func', name='redirect_test')
```

Then you can call redirect with the name of your url:

```
return redirect('redirect_test')
```

You can check the documentation on naming urls [here](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/http/urls/#naming-url-patterns)

Comment: The url you provided makes me figure out that I didn't set any url for the redirection itself... Thanks!